# How do i intertwine 2 variables accordingly in php?

Tags: php

How can connect two variables like this below in php, both variables will always have equal data at the initial stage.

```
$var1='2019-11-12,2019-11-21,2019-11-29';
$var2='Mastered,red,slave';


$result='2019-11-12, Mastered |2019-11-21,red |2019-11-29,slave';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out PHP's explode function for converting CSV ( comma separated value ) strings into PHP Arrays! [PHP Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

My example using your code:

```
$var1='2019-11-12,2019-11-21,2019-11-29';
$var2='Mastered,red,slave';

$var1array = explode(',', $var1);
$var2array = explode(',' ,$var2);

$result = $var1array[0].', '.$var2array[0].' |'.$var1array[1].', '.$var2array[1].' |'.$var1array[2].', '.$var2array[2];
echo $result; // 2019-11-12, Mastered |2019-11-21,red |2019-11-29,slave';
```

You can see i also use Concatenation, which is a string operation from PHP as well. Just make sure your strings will always have the same data format!